# Convert Azure Web App MySql implementation

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-web-app-service, cleardb

I created an Azure Web app with MySql in-app as database. In hindsight that was the wrong choice. I'd now like to convert to ClearDB. Is there a way to convert my web app for that or do I have to start over? There's no need to migrate the database.

Also, is ClearDB truly free? It says so in the Azure introduction but the ClearDB website doesn't mention free options.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Azure does not have an option for the switching database provider. You probably need to migrate the database by yourself.

> Is ClearDB truly free?

Yes, when you create a ClearDB you can choose the free tier **Mercury** like below:

[image]

Comment: There's no need to migrate the database. I can easily kick it up again. I just would like my website in the Azure portal to have all the features it would have if I chose "Web app + ClearDB" in the first place.